# How can I display results of a timer with a putText in C++ OpenCV?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, native

How can I display results od a timer with a putText in my OpenCV Android app? The is detecting features on the view from a camera and the main algorithm and the timer is written in C++. The full code of my C++ JNI file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL  
Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial3_Sample3View_FindFeatures(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jint 
width, jint height, jbyteArray yuv, jintArray bgra)   
{
jbyte* _yuv  = env->GetByteArrayElements(yuv, 0);
jint*  _bgra = env->GetIntArrayElements(bgra, 0);

Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);
Mat mbgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)_bgra);
Mat mgray(height, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);

//Please make attention about BGRA byte order
//ARGB stored in java as int array becomes BGRA at native level
cvtColor(myuv, mbgra, CV_YUV420sp2BGR, 4);

vector<KeyPoint> v;

OrbFeatureDetector  detector(1);
double t = (double)getTickCount();
detector.detect(mgray, v);
t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
putText(mbgra, t+" detection time", Point2f(100,100), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, Scalar(0,0,255,255), 2);
for( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    circle(mbgra, Point(v[i].pt.x, v[i].pt.y), 10, Scalar(0,0,255,255));
env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(bgra, _bgra, 0);
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(yuv, _yuv, 0); }}
```

The problem is in the line with putText: I get an error "invalid operands of types 'double' and 'char const [15]' to binary 'operator+'". Is my timer OK? How else can I display the results of it? I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

't' is of class double and the constant " detection time" is treated as a string.  String + double is something that the compiler doesn't understand, which is why it pukes on you.

Instead, try this approach:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << t;
s << " detection time";

putText(mbgra, s.str(), Point2f(100,100), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, Scalar(0,0,255,255), 2);
```

In the above code, the stringstream class has all the overloads built in to the "<<" operator such that it knows what to do with doubles and integers and strings and how to mash them together.  With a little more research in to the various attributes, you can get it to format the precision of decimel points and such.